# troubleshoot ping failure due to denied MAC address

Tags: networking, mac, ping, timeout, command-line-tool

Does anyone know of a tool (Windows or Linux) that will identify packets that get dropped on a network due to MAC filtering? In question [682774 (ping-printer-times-out-when-wireless-ok-when-wired)](https://superuser.com/questions/682774/ping-printer-times-out-when-wireless-ok-when-wired) I wish I had had such a tool. I would imagine that the ping made it as far as router, or maybe even to printer but not back. If that doesn't exist (as I suspect), is there any network troubleshooting tool or technique that I could have used?

Answer (score 1):

The tool to do this is of course Wireshark, or tcpdump, with macchanger. The trick consists in listening in on the regular network traffic, and checking the MACs of authorized clients. After you have built up a small number of MAC addresses which are indeed authorized to access the network in question, you can change the MAC address of your NIC, to clone one of the MAC addresses which are allowed. If MAC filtering is indeed in place, spoofing one of the legit MAC addresses will grant you access to the network.

Just try to avoid replicating IP addresses, which may occur if, for instance, address reservation has been set up. This in fact might prevent packets from reaching your NIC for reasons that have nothing to do with MAC filtering being in place, and might lead you to wrong conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wireshark to do packet captures. This would allow you to see network traffic over the WiFi when you do packet captures on a WiFi interface, and will allow you to see network traffic over the wired network if it's being directed to your computer (but there are ways around this).

That would help diagnose network issues because then you would be able to see where the packets get to before they disappear.

Not sure if it would have helped you in your original question, but for myself - Wireshark is my goto tool when troubleshooting network issues.